# drop down list in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="header-inner">
   <a href="" class="btn-link icon-set menu-hambuger-plus m-l-20 sm-no-margin hidden-sm hidden-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="quickview" data-toggle-element="#quickview"></a>
</div>



<div id="quickview" class="quickview-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
        <li class="">
            <a href="#quickview-notes" data-toggle="tab">Notes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#quickview-alerts" data-toggle="tab">Alerts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#quickview-chat" data-toggle="tab">Chat</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(function(){
    $('#quickview').on('click',function(){
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

When I click the icon it should display the list in #quickview. When I click the icon it goes to #quickview but it is not toggling the list.

Comment: what? there is no element with the class `quickview` so there is nothing to target

Comment: @davvv. you should put some effort into understanding the underlying issue before removing tags. Even if poorly worded, this question is a lot more about `css` and `bootstrap` than about `jQuery`. OP tried to combine two Bootstrap v4 components, and managed to break their markup and is now trying to fix it using jQuery. As a rule of thumb, try to only remove tags related to technologies you master. Tags are really important for indexing (hence for making people find answers faster).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu in this circumstance one did jump ahead with terrible haste and removed tags that should not have been removed. BUT whether I am a master or not; a tag that is not related will be removed. Mastery has nothing to do with being able to review and edit.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something - the jQuery just isn't showing the ul?

If so, I believe it's because your targeting is incorrect.

```
$(function(){
    $('#quickview').click(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, what's the css and rest of the source look like? It works for me with what you have.

Comment: Yes.. It is working if I do it standalone.. I think the problem is with css then..

Answer (score 1):

From your incomplete example, I deduce you're trying to control a tabbed section display from a dropdown element, using Bootstrap v4.

First of all, I must warn you it's a bad idea from usability point of view (most users will not understand that's a tabbed area and will never get to see what's inside the hidden tabs, because they won't open the dropdown.

To make it work, you don't need any custom JavaScript, it's already provided by Bootstrap, as long as you pay attention to their markup:

```css
head + body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.tab-content {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid #ddd;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select section</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#one" id="tab-1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="one" aria-selected="false">Section 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#two" id="tab-2" data-toggle="tab" href="#two" role="tab" aria-controls="twp" aria-selected="false">Section 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#three" id="tab-3" data-toggle="tab" href="#three" role="tab" aria-controls="three" aria-selected="false">Section 3</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#last" id="tab-4" data-toggle="tab" href="#last" role="tab" aria-controls="last" aria-selected="false">Last section</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tab-content p-3">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1">
      <p class="lead">Section 1
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet actually selfies iPhone, kinfolk polaroid cold-pressed direct trade pug umami bitters. Direct trade readymade viral, occupy fingerstache pickled actually wayfarers waistcoat whatever succulents. Pinterest mlkshk hell of brooklyn typewriter glossier farm-to-table occupy hoodie edison bulb. Trust fund truffaut pickled fixie, single-origin coffee tumeric cardigan gluten-free schlitz. Ugh quinoa single-origin coffee, ethical waistcoat art party biodiesel activated charcoal.
      </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="two" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-2">
    <p class="lead">Section 2
    <p>Listicle umami neutra, keytar man braid copper mug try-hard thundercats trust fund mixtape fanny pack. 90's you probably haven't heard of them tofu, tumblr umami stumptown freegan kickstarter typewriter keytar. Franzen food truck prism vice. Fashion axe fanny pack food truck flannel thundercats, subway tile XOXO kogi next level air plant pok pok. Tumblr marfa tumeric, four loko sriracha direct trade lumbersexual flexitarian vape selvage.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="three" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-3">
    <p class="lead">Section 3
    <p>Af XOXO biodiesel succulents live-edge fashion axe paleo poutine. Street art jianbing 8-bit echo park unicorn trust fund plaid austin lyft actually. Hella tacos selfies, twee normcore locavore coloring book banh mi. Farm-to-table pinterest gentrify glossier whatever enamel pin intelligentsia sustainable green juice selvage readymade.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="last" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-4">
    <p class="lead">Last Section
    <p>Oh. You need a little dummy text for your mockup? How quaint.
    <p>I bet you’re still using Bootstrap too…
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The CSS I added in is purely cosmetic, you don't need it for the example to work.

Comment: This page will be controlled by the Admin. So they should know what are the options available. The icon I used 'menu-hambuger-plus' explains there will be further options when you click on it. i will take your advise in and try to change some parts of the program.